# please look the below program and explai me why the error is given

Tags: plsql

```
create or replace package ins_emp
is
procedure insert_emp(
p_ename emp.ename%type,
p_sal emp.sal%type,
p_deptno emp.deptno%type);

end ins_emp;

create or replace package body ins_emp
is

function gen_no
return number
is

v_empno emp.empno%type;
begin
select max(empno) into v_empno from emp;
v_empno:=empno+1;
return v_empno;

end;
procedure insert_emp(
p_ename emp.ename%type,
p_sal emp.sal%type,
p_deptno emp.deptno%type)
is 
p_eno emp.empno%type;

begin


p_eno:=gen_no;

insert into emp(empno,ename,sal,deptno) values(p_eno,p_ename,p_sal,p_deptno);



end insert_emp;

end ;
```

In the above code package is created successfully.but package body is showing error as statement ignored identifier 'EMPNO' must be declared. i have run this program on sqlplus editor.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition of the `emp` table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function gen_no
return number
is
    v_empno emp.empno%type;
begin
    select max(empno) + 1 into v_empno from emp;

    return v_empno;
end;
```

You can not use empno outside the SQL part.